# Add extra value from ImportForm to model instance before imported or saved

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have the following model that I want to import:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(db_index=True,unique=True,primary_key=True,    )
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=State.VALID, choices=State.choices)
```

then a resource model:

```
class TokenResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = Token
    import_id_fields = ("key",)
```

and a ImportForm for querying the pool:

```
class AccessTokenImportForm(ImportForm):
pool = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Pool.objects.all(), required=True)
```

This value shouls be set for all the imported token objects.
The problem is, that I did not find a way to acomplish this yet.

How do I get the value from the form to the instance?

The before_save_instance and or similar methods I cannot access these values anymore. I have to pass this alot earlier I guess. Does someone ever done something similar?

Thanks and regards
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could pass the extra value in the Admin:

```
class TokenAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_import_data_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = kwargs.get('form')
    if form:
        kwargs.pop('form')

        if 'pool' in form.cleaned_data:
            return {'pool_id' : form.cleaned_data['pool'].id }

        return kwargs
    return {}
```

And then use this data within your resources after_import_instance method to set this value

```
def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
    pool_id = kwargs.get('pool_id')
    instance.pool_id = pool_id
    instance.created_at = timezone.now()
```

Then the error from missing field (non null) is gone.